# How to let the youtube video not playing automatic when loadVideo

Tags: android

I want to control play video by user not system , it plays automatically now. I try to use `youTuBePlayer.pause();` but it's not working.

How do i let the video be loaded , it's status is on pause ?

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getResources().getString(R.string.youTuBeApiKey), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(commonEducationObject.getHD_YouTubeID());
                //youTubePlayer.play();
                youTubePlayer.pause();//it's not working
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You want to disable the Auto playback of Youtube player?

Comment: I don not meant disable , i mean that it will show on pause when video be loaded at begining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried?

```
youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    yPlayer = player;
                    yPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    yPlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                // YouTube error
                String errorMessage = error.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you yPlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID); is working for me , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution !

```
youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoading() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoaded(String s) {
                            youTubePlayer.pause();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdStarted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVideoStarted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVideoEnded() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                        }
                    });
```